# dynamically define collection or object type variable in java

Tags: java, list, object, gson, dynamictype

I have seen number of matching questions but non answered my problem. I want to make following code snippet dynamic in a way that I am not sure that my API will return a single object or an array of objects.

```
List<Article> article = null;
```

I have seen different examples like below, but this does not answer my question:

```
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
```

The thing is, I have `article` variable defined in my Java *gson* model class, and I really have no idea how can I handle a response and make my `article` to behave dynamically. So, if there is a single object then it should act like single object instead of `List`, and if there is array of objects then it should act like `List`.

I am also not sure if something like this will work or not but I am looking for following type of functionality in any do able form:

```
<T> Article article = null;
```

Note: I have also seen this [Generic Type Doc.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_generics/java_generics_list.htm) but this doesn't help to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider extending the ArrayList with methods that internally perform aggregation methods so that externally it behaves the same whether there is 0, 1, or N number of internal objects.

```
class Articles extends ArrayList<Article> {...}
```

Comment: I like your approach, but can you please give me little more example, how this will actually be used and work.

Comment: Take a quick look at the example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson.  Notice that "public Car[] cars;" is within the class, yet accessing the data is performed via a method call that aggregates what is contained in the array.  If I understand your need, you can create aggregation methods that call internally upon the iterator from the superclass.  My suggestion is a is-a relationship whereas the wikipedia example is a has-a relationship, you'll need to assess which may be more appropriate.  What I assume, is that Gson can serialize/serialize collection classes like any other objects.

Answer (score 0):

Although @Jeff Stewart's answer might be a viable solution I would like to add something. If the type-safety is not an issue for your needs, you can consider also defining your `article` variable as `Object`. However, you should check your variable later when you use, something like:

```java
if(article instanceof Collection){
  // article is an array of objects  
} else {
  // article is a single object
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to @Jeff Stewart's idea I have implemented a more appropriate solution that can handle both single and multiple values in a single type.

Considering your API response something like this:

```
"article": {"name":"article1",...} 
 - or -  
"article": [{"name":"article1",...}, {"name":"article2",...}]
```

Let's create `ArticleList` derived from `java.util.ArrayList`

```java
/**
 * Custom type to handle both single Article and ArrayList<Article> types
 *
 * @author Yavuz Tas
 *
 */
public class ArticleList extends ArrayList<Article> {

}
```

After we implement a custom `JsonAdapter` for `ArticleList` type

```java
/**
 * Custom JsonAdapter for GSON to handle {@link ArticleList} converstion
 * 
 * @author Yavuz Tas
 *
 */
public class ArticleListJsonAdapter extends TypeAdapter<ArticleList> {

    /*
     * We just create another instance of GSON here in order to reuse their
     * predefined object and collection adapters
     */
    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private static final TypeAdapter<Article> objectTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(Article.class);
    private static final TypeAdapter<List<Article>> listTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(new TypeToken<List<Article>>() {
    });

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, ArticleList list) throws IOException {

        /*
         * Since we do not serialize ArticleList by gson we can omit this part but
         * anyway we can simply implement by reusing listTypeAdapter
         */
        listTypeAdapter.write(out, new ArrayList<Article>(list));

    }

    @Override
    public ArticleList read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {

        ArticleList deserializedObject = new ArticleList();

        // type of next token
        JsonToken peek = in.peek();

        // if the json field is single object just add this object to list as an
        // element
        if (JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT.equals(peek)) {
            Article object = objectTypeAdapter.read(in);
            deserializedObject.add(object);
        }

        // if the json field is array then implement normal array deserialization
        if (JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY.equals(peek)) {
            List<Article> list = listTypeAdapter.read(in);
            deserializedObject.addAll(list);
        }

        return deserializedObject;
    }
}
```

And last we register our adapter to our `article` field in GSON model that is used for API response and change its type to `ArticleList`:

```java
@JsonAdapter(value = ArticleListJsonAdapter.class)
@SerializedName("article")
@Expose
private ArticleList article;
```

Please note that any single `Article` response automatically added to `ArticleList` as a list element. You can alter this behavior by changing the implementation in the `read` method of `ArticleListJsonAdapter`.

I hope this helps too. Cheers!